# Skewed ggmap latitude and longitude in plot

Tags: r, google-maps

I cannot figure out why my `ggmap` plot is completely skewed. What I am trying to do is lay down the base layer and then add `geom_point()` over the top to mark cities. However, my initial state boundaries are very skewed and makes the state of Iowa appear more like Missouri. You can see the x scale is every 2 degrees of longitude while the y scale is 1 degree of latitude. What is causing this y scale transformation and how can I fix it?

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you need any clarification or have any questions!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

all_states <- map_data("state")
iowa <- all_states[which(all_states$region == "iowa"),]
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=iowa,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill="gray")
```

[image]

Comment: Look at `?coord_map`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Too easy! Thanks. If you want to submit `+ coord_map()` in addition to my code, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the projection type.

```
+ coord_map()
?maproject # the list of available projections
```

I don't know which projection is the one you need. 
You can also consult the ggplot2 documentation for more information.
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/coord_map.html